# Occasional JMS message delay on Solaris

Tags: java, jms, solaris

I have four separate processes which are listening for messages from one particular topic. The connection mode is DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE, and the TopicSubscriber is durable. Implementation is proprietary...

When the producer publishes a message, there is an occasional delay for some of the processes. For example, a message is published at 18:22:04 and the following happens (sometimes):

```
[18:22:04-Process1] Message1 received
[18:22:04-Process3] Message1 received
[18:22:06-Process2] Message1 received
[18:22:06-Process4] Message1 received
```

Notice the delay of 2 seconds for two of the processes. The receiving processes do not have any GC or similar during this time. And strangely enough, this behavior does not exist on Linux.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this behavior (except for a bug in the proprietary implementation)? Does it sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Run the process [under `truss`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/truss-1.html) to see what happens.  Something like `truss -f -a -vall -l -d -o /path/to/output/file -p PID` should work.  That will produce a *lot* of output, and finding the thread that exhibits the delay and the delay itself may be extremely tedious, but assuming it's an issue in the OS and not the JVM, you should be able to find it in the output somewhere.  And you might find it even if it is a JVM issue.  Find a receive that isn't slow, compare it to the slow one, and see what's different.